# Trouble dispatching Laravel Queue

Tags: php, laravel, message-queue, jobs

I am currently trying to send mail using a queue in Laravel 5.4 in order to speed up a few requests. But for some reason I just won't resolve.

My job looks like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class NotificationEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $doer, $does, $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  Podcast  $podcast
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($doer, $does, $user)
    {
        $this->doer = $doer;
        $this->does = $does;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @param  AudioProcessor  $processor
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $actions = [
            'accepted.invite' => 'accepted your invited.',
            'accepted.requesting' => 'accepted your request.',
            'denied.invite' => 'denied your invite.',
            'denied.requesting' => 'denied your request'
        ];
        Mail::send('emails.notification', [
            'doer' => $this->does,
            'action' => $actions[$this->action]
        ], function ($m)  {
            $m->from('noreply@bigriss.com', 'Bigriss');

            $m->to("myemail@gmail.com", 'Shawn')->subject('New Notification');

            echo "SENT";
        });
    }
}
```

With it being dispatched in another class by:

```
NotificationEmail::dispatch($doer, $does, $user);
```

Upon listening to the queue, `php artisan queue:listen`, as soon as I dispatch the job, the listener just runs on endlessly trying to resolve the handle function. I am getting the message "SENT" but the email is never sent (as I can see on my email provider) and the queue is never actually remove instead, the attempts count just goes up indefinitely. Am I missing something here? Is this not what queues are good for?

Comment: Any logging or try/catch to make sure that the handle function did run without any error?

Comment: I have tried a try/catch and it does not throw an exception. @JaredChu

Answer (score 1):

You are passing string into your `to` function, and you're missing a variable in your closure.

When you have an anonymous function, you need to pass in any extra variables using `use`. I don't see a `$user` variable anywhere in your handle method. It will need to be passed in as a separate variable because you cannot use `$this->user` to pass it into the closure.

Right now you have

```
$m->to("$user->email", 'Shawn')->subject('New Notification');
```

Which is literally interpreting that as a string that says **$user->email** because you haven't passed anything in. (Side note: there's really no reason to use that here, save that for inline variables with file paths, etc. You don't need an inline variable with this string).

You would need to change it to

```
$user = $this->user;
Mail::send('emails.notification', [
        'doer' => $this->does,
        'action' => $actions[$this->action]
    ], function ($m) use ($user)  {
        $m->from('noreply@bigriss.com', 'Bigriss');

        $m->to($user->email, 'Shawn')->subject('New Notification');

        echo "SENT";
    });
```

You may want to consider using something like [Laravel Dusk](https://github.com/laravel/dusk) to debug your queue and [logging](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#logging) to better control this than trying to just view "SENT" in your browser.

Also, consider sanitizing your website address since you're posting source code from it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the confusing, but during testing I actually used my real email without any variables in the closure hence the missing use statement so this is the true issue but I was not very clear about that. About the last part, why sanitize my address when this is nothing malicious or production code?

Comment: What's your mail configuration? I'd try to use [MailTrap](https://mailtrap.io/) or something similar to start. As far as sanitizing, it's just personal practice, you never know what questions you'll have in the future. I may just be paranoid though :P

Comment: I use mailgun, and it sends mail perfectly fine when I do not just the jobs but the request takes a bit